# Why oracle doesn't provide any Development Kit for Java Card 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 and 3.0.4?

Tags: javacard

I have a *JCOP v2.4.2 r3* smart card. It is written in its *Security Target* that my card support **Java Card 3.0.1 Classic edition**. I searched *Oracle* website to find a development kit to developing some applets for my card, But I couldn't find them. There are just a development kit for *Java Card 3.0.3*, while there are specifications for all the versions.

**Q1: How I can my ".java" files to ".cap" files for other versions except v3.0.3?**

Comment: Removed Q2: too broad. One question per question please, and don't forget to accept answers.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Is there any way to ask you questions in private? any email address or so on? I have some questions about the methodology of smart card testing based on Common Criteria, but I don't have any source to ask my questions from. Do you know any from or any friend that can help me in designing evaluation procedure for smart card's requirements? I asked you, because your profile mentions that  you was a "lead developer of a common criteria certified product"
 :) Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. Consultation about CC would take a lot of time (and if I'm ever going to consult on CC I will certainly require payment). Besides that, the *evaluation* should be performed by a lab that has been authorized by a certification body. Testing should be performed by a colleague or test team. There are specific requirements for testing a smart card product (e.g. card tear testing etc.). So you probably need to hire an expert or request support from the evaluator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A1: Please read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javacard/download/releasenotes-jsp-1440109.html

> The Java Card 3 platform consists of versions 3.0, 3.0.1 and 3.0.4 of the specifications and versions 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3 and 3.0.4 of the development kit.

SDK 3.0.3 targets specification 3.0.1.

A2: (also applies to A1) you can use [ant-javacard](https://github.com/martinpaljak/ant-javacard): open source, cross-platform, all JavaCard versions Ant task for working with the SDK: https://github.com/martinpaljak/ant-javacard

Comment: Dear Martin, I am trying to use _ant-havacard_.  I read the manual, but I don't understand following part: 

**Now you can create applets within your Ant targets like this:**

`<jcpro>
  <cap jckit="/path/to/jckit_dir" cap="0102030405" output="MyApplet.cap" sources="src/myapplet">
    <applet class="myapplet.MyApplet" aid="0102030405060708"/>
  </cap>
</jcpro>`

Where I must write this lines?